# Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 when Bind_param() with UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
public function deletePost($postId,$userId){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE post SET active_status = ? ,modified_by =? ,modified_time=? WHERE post_id=?");
    $notActivePost = 0;
    $currentTime = $this->getCurrentTime();
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$notActivePost,$userId,$currentTime,$postId);
    $res = $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($notActivePost,$currentTime,$postId,$userId);
    var_dump($stmt->error_list);
    return $res;
}
```

I checked the value of all the variable which is all correct,as below:

```
$notActivePost = 0 //I tried this also $notActivePost = "0",also not work
$currentTime = 2017-08-30 20:34:05
$postId = 606
$userId = 56
```

But I keep getting this error

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I check all the question about this error is because the column number in query not same with the number of variable binding in,but as you see is 4 column in query,and 4 variable I binding in.So I really don't know what's going on here.

Can somebody please help?Cause I tried some many ways already..tq

**EDIT:**

I tried this same code in localhost all going good.But this code run in live server,it produce the error.

Comment: Something is unclear to me. Your method is called `deletePost()` yet you want to run an UPDATE. Yet, you're passing two arguments in there rather than four.

Comment: You are sure that the message is regarding this code?

Comment: ya regarding this code

Comment: I don't know how picky mysqli is (I don't use it...), but your ID's are integers and not strings. As is `$notActivePost`.

Comment: @ken   read fred-ii comment

Comment: 2 variable which is `$notActivePost` and `$currentTime` I assign it within the function..2 variables is params

Comment: @Jens the logic / naming convention doesn't *fit* ;-)

Comment: @jeroen data type of the `active_status` is smallint(6) ,in this case,how to solve ya??

Comment: It probably doesn't make a difference, but `'ssss'` should be `'iisi'`. Or you use 2 parameters and `0` and `NOW()` in the query.

Comment: And you're 100% sure that the message above is coming from `var_dump($stmt->error_list);`? Have you actually checked the value of `$res`?

Comment: @PatrickQ `var_dump($res)` the result is  `bool(false)`

Comment: @jeroen use 0 and `NOW()` in the query,just make the server 500 internal error

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong :-)

Comment: Yup, there's definitely something else at play here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 10 more hours to figure it out what is the problem,finally I solve it.It actually cause by the trigger of the table but not the query itself.The number of the data count not match the column to insert in the trigger that cause this error

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Hope can help the future reader solve this problem.I suggest if the query is all correct,but still produce this error,just check the trigger of your table.

Comment: amazing! You solved a 6 months old problem I had fixed by breaking a feature without even realizing.. thanks for saving me hours of search

Comment: @Oleg I glad this helped you. Is my very old question, but still help, I glad

Answer (score 1):

need to pass `i` if field is of type integer.Considering active_status, modified_by and post_id as of type `integer`

DO the change from `ssss` to `iisi`

```
public function deletePost($postId,$userId){
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE post SET active_status = ? ,modified_by =? ,modified_time=? WHERE post_id=?");
    $notActivePost = 0;
    $currentTime = $this->getCurrentTime();
    $stmt->bind_param("iisi",$notActivePost,$userId,$currentTime,$postId);
    $res = $stmt->execute();
    var_dump($stmt->error_list);
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: It seems highly unlikely that this would solve the problem, why would it? But I'm not 100% sure so no DV from me :-)

Comment: @AlivetoDie I just get this error `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have run this code in localhost before..All doing well,but in live server it produce this error...